# To create a SOAPUI project using a wsdl

Tags: java, soapui

I want to create a SOAPUI project using a wsdl.

this is my code :

```
 File projectFile =new File("Test/sampleURI-soapui-project");
 SoapUI.setSoapUICore(new StandaloneSoapUICore(true));
 WsdlProject project = new WsdlProject("sampleURI");

 WsdlInterface[] wsdls = WsdlImporter.importWsdl(project, "http://192.168.18.171/sample/api/v2_soap/?wsdl");

 for(int j=0;j<wsdls.length;j++){
 WsdlInterface wsdl = wsdls[j];
 String soapVersion = wsdl.getSoapVersion().toString();
 int c = wsdl.getOperationCount();

 String reqContent="";
 String result="";

 for(int i=0;i<c;i++){
    WsdlOperation op = (WsdlOperation) wsdl.getOperationAt(i);
    String opName = op.getName();
    reqContent = op.createRequest(true);
    WsdlRequest req = op.addNewRequest("Req_"+soapVersion+"_"+opName);
    }
 }
```

I am getting the following error :

WARN  [SoapUI] Missing folder [D:\EclipsePrograms\kepler-workspace\Test.\ext] for external libraries
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans.typeSystemForClassLoader(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/SchemaTypeSystem;
    at com.eviware.soapui.config.SoapuiSettingsDocumentConfig.(Unknown Source)
    at com.eviware.soapui.config.SoapuiSettingsDocumentConfig$Factory.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.eviware.soapui.DefaultSoapUICore.initSettings(DefaultSoapUICore.java:211)
    at com.eviware.soapui.SwingSoapUICore.initSettings(SwingSoapUICore.java:118)
    at com.eviware.soapui.DefaultSoapUICore.init(DefaultSoapUICore.java:142)
    at com.eviware.soapui.StandaloneSoapUICore.(StandaloneSoapUICore.java:37)
    at sampleSoap.main(sampleSoap.java:20)

What jar file am I missing for getting this issue?.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is a possibility of having the same package name(com.xxx.yyy.zzz) in two different jars/wsdls. please make sure that there is only one such package in 2 different jars/wsdls

Answer (score 1):

This `typeSystemForClassLoader` method is introduced after version 2.0.0 of xbean .Use a greater version (2.1.0) for solving this issue. Compare [javadoc](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/reference/) of 2 versions

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>xmlbeans</groupId>
    <artifactId>xbean</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Exception. After using **SoapUI Pro** the Problem was solved.

You can try out the SoapUI Pro trial for 2 weeks at the moment.
Just imported the new SoapUI.jar and it works well.