# How to setup new SOAPUI project to Office 365 Exchange (trouble accessing WSDL)

Tags: soap, wsdl, soapui, exchangewebservices, office365

I'm trying to create a new [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) project for testing against Exchange Web Services in Office 365.

Attempt 1)

For the initial WSDL I specify https://outlook.office365.com/ews/services.wsdl.

SoapUI then prompts me for Basic Authentication for `outlook.office365.com:443`
If I enter the credentials that I use to login to Office365, this fails.

The login screen then comes back asking for Basic Authentication for `outlook.office365.com:-1`

Attempt 2)

Then I found this detailed guide [How to get services.wsdl for Office 365?](http://blog.skysoft-is.com/?p=78):
Using the [Microsoft Remote Connectivity Analyzer](https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/) I could extract `https://pod51046.outlook.com/ews/exchange.asmx`
So I next tried that, but then SoapUI responds:

```
"There was something wrong with the WSDL you are trying to import"
Error loading [https://pod51046.outlook.com/ews/exchange.wsdl]: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: Unexpected end of file after null
```

SoapUI Log says:

```
Tue Oct 14 13:35:48 CEST 2014:DEBUG:Getting wsdl component from [https://pod51046.outlook.com/ews/exchange.wsdl]
Tue Oct 14 13:35:48 CEST 2014:INFO:pod51046.outlook.com:443 requires authentication with the realm 'null'
Tue Oct 14 13:36:14 CEST 2014:ERROR:Failed to load url [https://pod51046.outlook.com/ews/exchange.wsdl]
Tue Oct 14 13:36:14 CEST 2014:ERROR:An error occurred [com.eviware.soapui.impl.support.definition.support.InvalidDefinitionException], see error log for details
```

HTTP log says:

```
Tue Oct 14 13:35:48 CEST 2014:DEBUG:>> "GET /ews/exchange.wsdl HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 14 13:35:48 CEST 2014:DEBUG:>> "Host: pod51046.outlook.com[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 14 13:35:48 CEST 2014:DEBUG:>> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 14 13:35:48 CEST 2014:DEBUG:>> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 14 13:35:48 CEST 2014:DEBUG:>> "Cookie: ClientId=LGJVIJZECEJQYUIHP0RW; X-BackEndCookie=jan@[snip].onmicrosoft.com=u56Lnp[snip]Fys0=; exchangecookie=0fe18[snip]ad43d[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 14 13:35:48 CEST 2014:DEBUG:>> "Cookie2: $Version=1[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 14 13:35:48 CEST 2014:DEBUG:>> "[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 14 13:35:48 CEST 2014:DEBUG:<< "HTTP/1.1 401 Anonymous Request Disallowed[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 14 13:35:48 CEST 2014:DEBUG:<< "Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 14 13:35:48 CEST 2014:DEBUG:<< "request-id: fadbe60a-008b-4f16-859a-719aaa8794bc[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 14 13:35:48 CEST 2014:DEBUG:<< "X-WSSecurity-Enabled: True[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 14 13:35:48 CEST 2014:DEBUG:<< "X-WSSecurity-For: Logon[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 14 13:35:48 CEST 2014:DEBUG:<< "X-FederationTrustTokenIssuerUri: urn:federation:MicrosoftOnline[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 14 13:35:48 CEST 2014:DEBUG:<< "X-WSSecurity-SymmetricKey-Enabled: True[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 14 13:35:48 CEST 2014:DEBUG:<< "X-WSSecurity-X509Cert-Enabled: True[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 14 13:35:48 CEST 2014:DEBUG:<< "X-OAuth-Enabled: True[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 14 13:35:48 CEST 2014:DEBUG:<< "X-Powered-By: ASP.NET[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 14 13:35:48 CEST 2014:DEBUG:<< "X-FEServer: AM2PR02CA0041[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 14 13:35:48 CEST 2014:DEBUG:<< "WWW-Authenticate: Basic Realm=""[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 14 13:35:48 CEST 2014:DEBUG:<< "Date: Tue, 14 Oct 2014 11:35:55 GMT[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 14 13:35:48 CEST 2014:DEBUG:<< "Content-Length: 0[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 14 13:35:48 CEST 2014:DEBUG:<< "[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 14 13:36:14 CEST 2014:DEBUG:>> "GET /ews/exchange.wsdl HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 14 13:36:14 CEST 2014:DEBUG:>> "Host: pod51046.outlook.com[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 14 13:36:14 CEST 2014:DEBUG:>> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 14 13:36:14 CEST 2014:DEBUG:>> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 14 13:36:14 CEST 2014:DEBUG:>> "Cookie: ClientId=LGJVIJZECEJQYUIHP0RW; X-BackEndCookie=jan@[snip].onmicrosoft.com=u56Lnp2ejJ[snip]vFys0=; exchangecookie=0fe1867420a243b5993d336bbbead43d[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 14 13:36:14 CEST 2014:DEBUG:>> "Cookie2: $Version=1[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 14 13:36:14 CEST 2014:DEBUG:>> "Authorization: Basic amFuQFR[snip]RCVg==[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 14 13:36:14 CEST 2014:DEBUG:>> "[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 14 13:36:14 CEST 2014:DEBUG:<< "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 14 13:36:14 CEST 2014:DEBUG:<< "Cache-Control: private[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 14 13:36:14 CEST 2014:DEBUG:<< "Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 14 13:36:14 CEST 2014:DEBUG:<< "request-id: 0bdf26cb-0fe3-418e-816f-a07324900119[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 14 13:36:14 CEST 2014:DEBUG:<< "X-CalculatedBETarget: db3pr02mb203.eurprd02.prod.outlook.com[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 14 13:36:14 CEST 2014:DEBUG:<< "X-DiagInfo: DB3PR02MB203[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 14 13:36:14 CEST 2014:DEBUG:<< "X-BEServer: DB3PR02MB203[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 14 13:36:14 CEST 2014:DEBUG:<< "X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 14 13:36:14 CEST 2014:DEBUG:<< "Set-Cookie: X-BackEndCookie=jan@[snip].onmicrosoft.com=u56Lnp2ejJqBy[snip]7FzMnFzc4=; expires=Thu, 13-Nov-2014 11:36:21 GMT; path=/ews; secure; HttpOnly[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 14 13:36:14 CEST 2014:DEBUG:<< "X-Powered-By: ASP.NET[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 14 13:36:14 CEST 2014:DEBUG:<< "X-FEServer: AM2PR02CA0041[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 14 13:36:14 CEST 2014:DEBUG:<< "Date: Tue, 14 Oct 2014 11:36:20 GMT[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 14 13:36:14 CEST 2014:DEBUG:<< "Content-Length: 0[\r][\n]"
Tue Oct 14 13:36:14 CEST 2014:DEBUG:<< "[\r][\n]"
```

Error log says:

```
Tue Oct 14 13:36:14 CEST 2014:ERROR:com.eviware.soapui.impl.support.definition.support.InvalidDefinitionException
com.eviware.soapui.impl.support.definition.support.InvalidDefinitionException
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.wsdl.WsdlLoader.makeInvalidDefinitionException(WsdlLoader.java:142)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.wsdl.WsdlLoader.loadXmlObject(WsdlLoader.java:129)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.xsd.SchemaUtils.getDefinitionParts(SchemaUtils.java:539)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.xsd.SchemaUtils.getDefinitionParts(SchemaUtils.java:528)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.support.definition.support.AbstractDefinitionCache.update(AbstractDefinitionCache.java:101)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.support.definition.support.AbstractDefinitionContext$Loader.construct(AbstractDefinitionContext.java:240)
at com.eviware.soapui.support.swing.SwingWorkerDelegator.construct(SwingWorkerDelegator.java:50)
at com.eviware.soapui.support.swing.SwingWorker$2.run(SwingWorker.java:153)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Attempt 3)

If I put `https://pod51046.outlook.com/ews/exchange.wsdl` into the IE address bar it keeps prompting me for a login in IE.
That repeated prompting is mentioned in a comment here: [How to access a wsdl URL in SoapUI, which requires username/password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21690574/how-to-access-a-wsdl-url-in-soapui-which-recquires-username-password), but after 3 logins (each time telling IE to remember my references) the returned page is blank:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML><HEAD>
<META content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" http-equiv=Content-Type></HEAD>
<BODY></BODY></HTML>
```

I'm using the free SOAPUI 5.0.0 (latest version), with Java 7 (then 8) in a Win7/64 environment.
I have also cloned my VM and tried the SOAPUI Pro version as suggested in [To create a SOAPUI project using a wsdl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20660192/to-create-a-soapui-project-using-a-wsdl), but this did not help.

**Any suggestions how to get this to work?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right URL to use for Office 365 EWS WSDL is the first one you tried: https://outlook.office365.com/ews/services.wsdl.  You should use this URL to get the WSDL.  From the browser, when I enter my email address and password, I am able to get the WSDL without any problems.

I am not familiar with SOAPUI, so I am not sure why this URL + Basic auth isn't working with SOAP UI.  Let me know if you have any questions or need more info.

**[Additional notes by OP]**

Thanks Venkat, that was the solution. There were additional complications why I did not get this correct in the first place. I'm writing them in the answer, because it's too much for comments.

1. I accidentally entered `https://pod51046.outlook.com/ews/***exchange***.wsdl`
   instead of `https://pod51046.outlook.com/ews/***services***.wsdl` (which Oleg's blog actually mentioned, and I overlooked). This immediately gave the correct results in IE. *Your* suggestion of inputting the *generic* `https://outlook.office365.com/ews/services.wsdl` also works.
   (I think that after having read somewhere that the *actual* URL is a `pod...` one, I doggedly kept trying that one after resolving it).
   *So this is why attempts 2 and 3 failed*.
2. SOAP UI asks me 2 times 3 = 6 times for the login credentials when setting up the test project. I just was not persistent enough.
   *And this is why attempt 1 failed*.

Comment: The reason it keeps asking for your credentials is to get the related XSD's and wsdl mentioned in the original .wsdl.  So just keep typing and have faith.